# How to project more than one value with doctrine mongodb query builder selectElemMatch

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-query

I have the following kind of data in my mongo database. The property "values" consists of an array of attributes. "values" is a property of a product, which also has some other properties like "normalizedData". But the structure of "values" is what gives me a headache.

```
"values" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a09d88c83218b814a8df57d"),
        "attribute" : NumberLong("118"),
        "entity" : DBRef("pim_catalog_product", ObjectId("59148ee283218bb8548b45a8"), "akeneo_pim"),
        "locale" : "de_AT",
        "varchar" : "LED PAR-56 TCL 9x3W Short sw"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a09d88c83218b814a8df57a"),
        "attribute" : NumberLong("118"),
        "entity" : DBRef("pim_catalog_product", ObjectId("59148ee283218bb8548b45a8"), "akeneo_pim"),
        "locale" : "de_DE",
        "varchar" : "LED PAR-56 TCL 9x3W Short sw"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a09d88c83218b814a8df57c"),
        "attribute" : NumberLong("184"),
        "entity" : DBRef("pim_catalog_product", ObjectId("59148ee283218bb8548b45a8"), "akeneo_pim"),
        "locale" : "de_AT",
        "boolean" : false
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a09d88c83218b814a8df585"),
        "attribute" : NumberLong("118"),
        "entity" : DBRef("pim_catalog_product", ObjectId("59148ee283218bb8548b45a8"), "akeneo_pim"),
        "locale" : "fr_FR",
        "varchar" : "LED PAR-56 TCL 9x3W Short sw"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a09d88c83218b814a8df584"),
        "attribute" : NumberLong("121"),
        "entity" : DBRef("pim_catalog_product", ObjectId("59148ee283218bb8548b45a8"), "akeneo_pim"),
        "locale" : "fr_FR",
        "varchar" : "Eurolite LED PAR-56 TCL 9x3W Short sw"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a09d88c83218b814a8df574"),
        "attribute" : NumberLong("207"),
        "entity" : DBRef("pim_catalog_product", ObjectId("59148ee283218bb8548b45a8"), "akeneo_pim"),
        "varchar" : "51913611"
    },
]
```

A couple of things to notice about this extract from the dataset:

- attributes with their ID ("attribute") can appear multiple times, like 118 for example.
- attributes do not always have the same subset of properties (see 207 and 121 for example).
- if an attribute is present multiple times (like 118) it should differ in the "locale" property at least.

Now I need the doctrine mongoDB query builder to project the following result:

- I want only those attributes to be present in the result that contain one of the IDs specified by the query (e.g. array(118, 184)).
- If the attribute exists multiple times, I want to see it multiple times.
- If the attribute exists multiple times, I want to limit the number by an array of locales given.

So an example query would be: return all attributes inside "values" that have eigther 118 or 184 as the "attribute" property, and (if specified) limit the results to those attributes, where the locale is either "de_DE" or "it_IT".

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
$qb = $productRepository->createQueryBuilder();
$query = $qb
    ->hydrate(false)
    ->select(array('normalizedData.sku'))
    ->selectElemMatch(
        'values',
        $qb->expr()->field('attribute')->in(array(117, 110))->addAnd(
            $qb->expr()->field('locale')->in(array('it_IT', 'de_DE'))
        ))
    ->field('_id')->in($entityIds)
    ->field('values')->elemMatch($qb->expr()->field('attribute')->in(array(117, 110)))
    ->limit($limit)
    ->skip($offset);
```

This query always returns only one attribute (no matter how many times it is present within the "values" array) per product. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: My MongoDB version is 2.4.9 and doctrine-mongo-odm is below 1.2. Currently I cannot update either.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below aggregation query in 3.4 mongo version. `$elemMatch` by design returns first matching element.

You will need [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to return multiple matches.

[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) to limit the documents were values has atleast one value where it contains both attribute in [118,184] and locale in ["de_DE","it_IT"] followed by [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to limit to matching documents in a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage. You can add [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) and [`$skip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/) stage at the end of aggregation pipeliine same as what you did with regular query.

```
db.col.aggregate([
  {"$match":{
    "values":{
      "$elemMatch":{
        "attribute":{"$in":[118,184]},
        "locale":{"$in":["de_DE","it_IT"]}
      }
    }
  }},
  {"$project":{
    "values":{
      "$filter":{
        "input":"$values",
        "as":"item",
        "cond":{
          "$and":[
            {"$in":["$$item.attribute",[118,184]]},
            {"$in":["$$item.locale",["de_DE","it_IT"]]}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

You can use [`AggregationBuilder`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/aggregation-builder.html) to write the query in doctrine.

Comment: Hi thank you, that looks like just what I need. Is there a way to do this without the aggregation builder? I am afraid I have to use doctrine mondo odm below 1.2 :(

Comment: Np. I don't think so unless you do it on client side. I'm not familiar with mongo odm to give you any suggestions. Can you run direct aggregation query using mongo php driver ?

Comment: The Mongo DB version I am stuck with is 2.4.9. I am screwed, right?

Comment: No, you should be okay. I can update the answer for lower versions but you need to find a way to run aggregation query with or without odm. Let me know.